# Stateless Lambda and Private members

Tags: c++11, lambda, private-members

In certain cases when programming with libraries written in C involving callbacks, I like to use Lambda expressions; however, if I need to alter the state of a class member variable I can't juts pass `this` into a stateless(function pointer) lambda. But I can assign `this` to a data in a context structure. What I find strange is being able to access that member variable even if it's private in the class.
Here's an example code I wrote to demonstrate.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
typedef struct extradatatype{
    void* data;
}extradata;
extradata e = {0};
typedef void(*callback)(extradata* e);
void cb(callback c){
    c(&e);
}

class Test{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Test(int x){
        this->x = x;
    }
    void setcb(){
        cb([](extradata* e){
            Test* self = reinterpret_cast<Test*>(e->data);
            self->x = 20;
        });
    }

    int getx(){
        return x;
    }
};

int main(){
    Test t(10);
    e.data = &t;
    t.setcb();
    cout << t.getx();

    return 0;
}
```

In the Lambda expression `Test* self` is assigned to `e->data` but I can access `self->x` as if it were a public member instead of private. So what I'm confused about is, is the lambda expression expression being executed within the stack/context of the `setcb` function or is it being executed elsewhere as its own function but C++ is doing some weird trick to allow private members to be accessed. Because I assume a stateless lambda is really no different than a non member static function which has no access to private members of a class.

Comment: A lambda inside `setcb` has the same access as `setcb` itself, and can do anything that `setcb` can do. Lambdas would have been very annoying to write otherwise. It doesn't matter where the lambda is executed - access checks are performed at compile time, not run time.

Comment: Why do you assume that the lambda is like a **non-member** static function, specifically? Why can't it be like a member static function (which is somewhat closer to reality)? A static member function would satisfy both properties - have access to private members, and could be passed as a C-style callback.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Actually yes. That does make sense. It is more like a member static function instead of non-member static function. I think since it was a lambda I somehow believed its executed in a context outside of class Test because I can't implicitly use `this`

Answer (score 0):

Since your lambda function is defined within the class `Test` context, it will have access to class `Test` private member (regardless if it's `this.x` or `self.x` where `self` is of type `Test`). It is similar to this example:

```cpp
class Example {
private:
    int x;
public:
    int f(Example e) {
        return e.x;
    }
};
```

where, since `f` is a member of `Example`, it can access `e.x` because `e` has type `Example`.

If you move your lambda function definition out of the class context you'll see the expected error message:

```cpp
void outside(extradata* e);

class Test{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void setcb(){
        cb(outside);
    }
};

void outside(extradata* e) {
    Test* self = reinterpret_cast<Test*>(e->data);
    self->x = 20;  // error here!
}
```

```
test.cpp:32:11: error: 'int Test::x' is private within this context
     self->x = 20;
           ^
```

Comment: Oh okay so even if you had passed a pointer of another class object rather itself it would still have access to the private members since it's executed within the context of the class itself; So it literally is a static member function which can't use `this` but it can access private members

Comment: Kind of like that, yes. It will be able to use `this` though, if you capture it: `[this](....){....}` - that way `this` will be available in your lambda.

Comment: When lambda is used in place of a function pointer, you can't capture `this` in the context though.